# Need to display document title in search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I am using out of the box search to display policies in a document library. The documents I received are all marked using the policy number as the name field  and the title in the title field. By default the returned results display the name field but doesn't display the title so it is difficult for a user to see what the policy is - is there a way to also display title?

Sorry I should have made clear this is for results when searching site and the results rendered on search.aspx page
[image: Searchbox]

[image: Results]

The results show name in blue and location but I also want to display title

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the name is displayed by default in the library, and the title is not displayed. If you want to display the title, then you can go to the setting in the view to display the title column.

Go to **libarary settings>Views>All items**, and check the **Title** column:
[image]
Then you can display the title column when you search again:
[image]